# Adding JavaScript To Many Pages(More than 500) in asp.net without MasterPage

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, page-lifecycle

I am working on Project in which there are more than 500 .aspx pages(Popups uses ShowModelDialog) I want Suppress/Disable Enter Key for each Page

I want to Add Below Code for Every page (all Popup )or for every Request made by User. **Unfortunately There is no master page in the project**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function stopRKey(evt) {
  var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
  var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
  if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=="text"))  {return false;}
}

document.onkeypress = stopRKey;

</script> 

void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
        System.Web.UI.Page mypage = (System.Web.UI.Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
        if (mypage != null)
        {
            mypage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "MyScriptKey", "alert('hi')", true);
        }

    }
```

I try to add this script in `Global.asax` in `Application_BeginRequest` but no luck

Comment: You didn't show the code you're using to add the script, but session start is undoubtedly the wrong place to do that. Perhaps you're approaching this from the wrong point- you should be using master pages to abstract common functionality rather than trying to jerry rig it somewhere else.

Comment: Why not introduce a master page?

Comment: @Stilgar it will took longs time as there are many pages in the project

Comment: I think create a class, do your page inherit with that, on the class use a ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript to inject the js?

Comment: @mason now updated and i added it in `BeginRequest` but i always get page as `null`

Comment: If you've got a poor architecture, its going to take a long time to do anything.  Best to bite the bullet and make it right.

Comment: Can you edit the physical files? You could add the js by doing a search and replace on all files. Best place to add some js and have it work is just before the end of the document.

Comment: @WilfredoP yeah that is one ways....but i am finding for quicker ones

Comment: @A.Rama can you show some links to elaborate this

Comment: @Ganesh_Devlekar Paqo, Stilgar, and myself are telling you that it'd be best to just do the work up front and add master pages to your site. Yes, it will take some time, but you'll have a better, more modular architecture.

Comment: @mason ok....thanks for all of you

Comment: You can utilize HTTP modules for your app and inject the script tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.140).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute` event in `Global.asax` file and it worked.

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
        Page mypage = context.CurrentHandler as Page;
        if (mypage != null)
        {

            mypage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"function stopRKey(evt) {
          var evt = (evt) ? evt : ((event) ? event : null);
          var node = (evt.target) ? evt.target : ((evt.srcElement) ? evt.srcElement : null);
          if ((evt.keyCode == 13) && (node.type=='text'))  {return false;}
           }
            document.onkeypress = stopRKey; ", true);


            mypage.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), @"function validatedot(val, evt) {
            var theEvent = evt || window.event;
            var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
            key = String.fromCharCode(key);

            y = val.value.split(/\./);

            var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

            if (y.length > 1 && key == '.') {

                theEvent.returnValue = false;
                if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
            }
            if (!regex.test(key)) {

                if (theEvent.keyCode != 8 && theEvent.keyCode != 9) {
                    //alert('Enter only number');
                    //alert(theEvent.keyCode);
                    theEvent.returnValue = false;
                    if (theEvent.preventDefault) theEvent.preventDefault();
                }
            }


        }", true);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to edit a large number of files, how to do it strongly depends on which platform you're working on and what tools do you have at your disposal.

On Windows, I would use Notepad++. With it you can do a search and replace on multiple files on a subdirectory, filtering only certain types of files (*.asp or *.php) and using regular expressions to search and modify text:

CTRL-F to open the find dialog.
Go to "Find in files" tab.
Select Directory and filters as appropriate.
Select "Search Mode" = "Regular Expression" and
use

```
(</body>)
```

for "Find What" field and

```
***YOUR SCRIPT IN A SINGLE LINE HERE*** \r\n \1
```

for "Replace with" field.

Note the "\1" that is used to place the closing body tag again in the file (otherwise it would be overwritten).

On unix and mac, you could probably use some equivalent text editors with PCRE regular expression editing functions but I'm afraid I cannot help you there.